# integral involving log poisson-like and rational

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Perhaps some may enjoy giving this one a go. It may be kind of challenging.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^{2}+b^{2}}\log\left(\frac{x^{2}+2ax\cos(t)+a^{2}}{x^{2}-2ax\cos(t)+a^{2}}\right)dx$$

$$=\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}-\pi t+\pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(a^{2}-b^{2})\cos(t)}{(a^{2}+b^{2})\sin(t)+2ab}\right), \;\ a,b>0; \;\ 0<t<\pi$$

Comment: I have a rough idea. Convert to complex exponential then differentiate with respect to t. Then we can solve the resultant integral using residues. It remains to find the anti derivative of the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$I(t)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+b^2}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+2ax\cos(t)+a^2}{x^2-2ax\cos(t)+a^2}\right)\,dx$$
$$I'(t)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+b^2}\left(\frac{-2ax\sin(t)}{x^2+2ax\cos(t)+a^2}-\frac{2ax\sin(t)}{x^2-2ax\cos(t)+a^2}\right)\,dx$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow I'(t) \,& =-2a\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+b^2}\left(\frac{x\sin(t)}{x^2+2ax\cos(t)+a^2}+\frac{x\sin(t)}{x^2-2ax\cos(t)+a^2}\right)\,dx\\
& =-2a\,\Im\left(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+b^2}\left(\frac{e^{it}}{x+ae^{it}}+\frac{e^{it}}{x-ae^{it}}\right)\,dx\right)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)\\
& = -2a\,\Im\left(2e^{it} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+b^2)(x^2-a^2e^{2it})}\,dx \right)\\
& = -2a\,\Im\left(2e^{it}\frac{\pi}{2(b-iae^{it})}\right)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)\\
& = -2\pi a\,\Im\left(\frac{e^{it}}{b-iae^{it}}\right)\\
& = -2\pi a\,\frac{b\sin t+a}{b^2+2ab\sin t+a^2}\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)\\
& = -\pi\left(1+\frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2+2ab\sin(t)+a^2}\right)\\
\end{aligned}$$

$$\Rightarrow I(t)=-\pi t-2\pi\arctan\left(\frac{(a^2+b^2)\tan(t/2)+2ab}{a^2-b^2}\right)+C\,\,\,\,\,\,(4)$$
Since $I(\pi/2)=0$, $C=\frac{\pi^2}{2}+2\pi\arctan\left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)$. 
$$\Rightarrow I(t)=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi t-2\pi\arctan\left(\frac{(a^2+b^2)\tan(t/2)+2ab}{a^2-b^2}\right)+2\pi\arctan\left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)$$
The above expression can be shown equivalent to as shown in OP by simplifying arctangents:
$$\begin{aligned}
-2\pi\left(\arctan\left(\frac{(a^2+b^2)\tan(t/2)+2ab}{a^2-b^2}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)\right) &=2\pi\arctan\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\frac{1-\sin(t)}{\cos t}\right)\\
&=\pi\arctan\left(\frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos(t)}{(a^2+b^2)\sin(t)+2ab}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
Hence
$$I(t)=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi t+\pi\arctan\left(\frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos(t)}{(a^2+b^2)\sin(t)+2ab}\right)$$

---

Proof of $(1)$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{x\sin t}{x^2+2ax\cos(t)+a^2}&=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{x(e^{it}-e^{-it})}{x^2+axe^{it}+axe^{-it}+a^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{e^{it}}{x+ae^{it}}-\frac{e^{-it}}{x+ae^{-it}}\right)\\
&= \Im\left(\frac{e^{it}}{x+ae^{it}}\right)\,\,\,\,\,\,\left(\because \Im(z)=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar{z})\right)\\
\end{aligned}$$

Similarly it can be shown that:
$$\frac{x\sin t}{x^2-2ax\cos(t)+a^2}=\Im\left(\frac{e^{it}}{x-ae^{it}}\right)$$

---

Proof for $(2)$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+b^2)(x^2-a^2e^{2it})}\,dx &=\frac{1}{b^2+a^2e^{2it}}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+b^2}-\frac{x^2}{x^2-a^2e^{2it}}\right)\,dx\\
&= -\frac{1}{b^2+a^2e^{2it}}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{b^2}{x^2+b^2}+\frac{a^2e^{2it}}{x^2-a^2e^{2it}}\right)\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{b^2+a^2e^{2it}} \left(\frac{\pi b}{2}+\frac{\pi iae^{it}}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{(b+iae^{it})(b-ia^{it})}(b+iae^{it})\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2(b-iae^{it})}\\
\end{aligned} $$

---

Proof for $(3)$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\Im\left(\frac{e^{it}}{b-iae^{it}}\right) &= \Im\left(\frac{\cos(t)+i\sin(t)}{(b+a\sin(t))-ia\cos(t)}\right)\\
&=\Im\left(\frac{(cos(t)+i\sin(t))(b+a\sin(t)+ia\cos(t))}{(b+\sin(t))^2+a^2\cos^2(t)}\right)\\
&= \frac{b\sin (t)+a}{b^2+2ab\sin(t)+a^2}\\
\end{aligned}$$

---

Proof for $(4)$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2+2ab\sin(t)+a^2}\,dt &=(a^2-b^2)\int \frac{\sec^2(t/2)}{(a^2+b^2)(1+\tan^2(t/2))+4ab\tan(t/2)}\,dt\\
&= 2(a^2-b^2)\int \frac{dp}{(a^2+b^2)(1+p^2)+4abp}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left(p=\tan(t/2)\right)\\
&=2\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}\int\frac{dp}{p^2+\frac{4abp}{a^2+b^2}+1}\\
&=2\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}\int \frac{dp}{\left(p+\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2}\\
&=2\arctan\left(\frac{(a^2+b^2)\tan(t/2)+2ab}{a^2-b^2}\right)+C\\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Comment: @RandomVariable: Thanks a lot! :) Do you have some ideas about showing that my last expression is same as shown in OP? I am really struggling with that.

Comment: @RandomVariable: Sorry, I was being hasty, I have proved that the expression is equivalent to shown in OP. :)

Comment: Nice work PA. :)  very thorough.

Comment: @Cody: Thank you! Glad to know you like it. :)

Comment: Nice, this how I would do it.